# Excel: Looping through rows and returning an Array of values

Tags: arrays, excel

In Excel, I'm attempting to loop through rows of data and return an array, based on an 'IF' statement checking values in one of the columns.  When I use an IF checking for a single value, it produces what it's supposed to; when I use an IF-OR (shown below), looking to return all rows containing one of two values in the specified column, it doesn't work - instead, it returns all the rows.  Any thoughts?

`{=IF($A$5<>"",IFERROR(INDEX('Interface Catalogue'!$E$5:$E$333,SMALL(IF(OR('Interface Catalogue'!$H$5:$H$333="Core (Built)",'Interface Catalogue'!$H$5:$H$333="Core (To Be Built)"),ROW('Interface Catalogue'!$H$5:$H$333)-ROW('Interface Catalogue'!$H$5)+1),ROW(1:1))),""),"")}`

Answer (score 0):

Please try rewriting your IF statements like this:

```
IF($H$5 = "Core Built" Or $H$5 = "Core To Be Built")
```

This will evaluate to true if either condition is true.

Comment: I tried this:

IF($A$5<>"",IFERROR(INDEX('Interface Catalogue'!$E$5:$E$333,SMALL(IF('Interface Catalogue'!$H$5:$H$333="Core (Built)" OR 'Interface Catalogue'!$H$5:$H$333="Core (To Be Built)",ROW('Interface Catalogue'!$H$5:$H$333)-ROW('Interface Catalogue'!$H$5)+1),ROW(1:1))),""),"")

It's telling me there's a problem with the formula

Comment: You might be missing a parenthesis somewhere: when I try to format the formula it does not work. Can you simplify to its most basic parts, then gradually add complexity? 

1) Start with IF(A5<>"","Yes","")


2) Change to IF(A5<>"",Index('Interface Catalogue'!$E$5:$E$333,1,ROW(1:1)),"")


3) etc. Each step you add another subformula and test to see if there are errors. If there are no errors, add more complexity. Repeat until you get the data you need. 

It may be helpful to share the excel workbook if you are comfortable with it